# Android WebView Download

Tags: java, android, image, webview, download

So, i have webview with some photos, and i want to add download button on them so i can save them on mobile.
Problem is when i click on button i get full size image and it is not downloading.
I tried to use:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

but it is not working.

My code is simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

On website, code for downloading is:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['img']; ?>" download>
 <div id="download">
  <img width="45" height="45" src="img/download.png">
 </div>
</a>
```